# SharePoint 2013 Library retrieving all file names. REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a library on Sharepoint 2013 and retrieving all the parameters (using angularjs on the client side.) using the following code.

```
var spListURL = siteURL + "_api/lists/getByTitle%28%27" + docLibName + "%27%29/items";
$http.get(spListURL,
{ headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", } }).success(function (result) {
    dfd.resolve(result);
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    errorFactory.buildError(data, status, headers, ORIGIN_VIEW_NAME);
});
```

However the result does not contain the file name or file url. I need to create an anchor link to the file. It does contain the custom parameters that I have added to the List/Lib.

I have never worked with SharePoint before. The client code is a snippet of an angularjs factory and it is working (as far as js is concerened).

I **do not want to make another rest** call using `d.result[index].File.__deffered.uri` and then open the document in a new blank window.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try asking over at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the

> FileLeafRef

in your url

```
site/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('LibraryName')/items?$top=1000&$select=FileLeafRef
```

Comment: also FileDirRef is needed usually

Answer (score 9):

How to retrieve file name using SharePoint REST

**Option 1**

Via `FileLeafRef` List Item property

REST endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef
```

**Option 2**

Via `File` `Name` property:

REST endpoint:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File
```